# Probability of collisions using "Luhn algorithm"

Tags: probability

The problem can be approximated to finding collisions in the following scheme also known as [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm):

birthdate 1981-03-14 becomes number 810314.

We perform some algebra on that number, doubling every second element:

```
8 * 2 = 16
1 * 1 = 1
0 * 2 = 0
3 * 1 = 3
1 * 2 = 2
4 * 1 = 4
```

We sum all individual digits from the right side: 1+6+1+3+2+4 = 17.

We then take 10 - 17 mod 10 = 3 and that number is the checksum number.

What is the probability of collision for two different dates? We can assume that births are evenly distributed between 1970 and 2000 or similar realistic assumption.

What is the probability of collision, or approximately a bounds if we have two ten-digit (or 12-digits if we include century "19" or 20" at the start) with [the following format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_identity_number_(Sweden)):

A child was born on the date 1991-03-14 and therefore the identification number will begin with 910314 (or in some instances 19910314). Then another four decimal numbers follow, where the first two of these four possibly are sequential at what time the child was born or random. I could research the real examples. Then the third decimal digit is odd if the child is male and even if the child is female.

What is the probability that two random people meet and have exactly the same four last digits?

The unconditional probability of four decimal digits being the same is trivially 0.0001 = (1/10)(1/10)(1/10)(1/10). In this case we know that the third digit is odd and therefore the probability is at least (1/10)(1/10)(1/5)(1/10) = 0.0002. But can we make the bounds tighter when the last digit is calculated as a checksum according to the following real example when two people don't share the same birthday but the four last digits of their personal id number is the same.

"What's the probability that two Swedish men meet and their four last digits of the personal identification numbers are the same?"

It's not trivial because the last digit is checksum calculated as follows

Example personal id number first 9 digits

81 01 11 00 5

First 6 digits are the date of birth (this example January 11 in year 1981), then the 9th digit is odd for male and even for female and the last digit is calculated as follows

```
8 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 5
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
161 0 1 2 1 0 0 10
```

with integer sum 1+6+1+0+1+2+1+0+0+0+1+0=13 which is 7 integers from the next 10th (20) or mathematically:

$$ 10 - x \mod 10 = 7$$

for x = 13, so the last digit in this example would be 7 if I created it correctly (contrived). I don't know if the first two of the last four digits are simple sequential or where they come from.

Edit: The third row is multiplied the two rows above e.g. 8 * 2 = 16, 1 * 1 = 1 etc, multiplying every other with 2 and every other with 1. Then the checksum is sum of all the digits from that third row.

Example:

81 01 11 0057

year (1981)
month (01 i.e. January)
date (11th of January)

00 ?? not sure what it is
5 (odd for male)
7 (checksum number as described above)

The operation is similar an inner product which adds all the digits:

$[8,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,5] \cdot [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2] = 16 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 10 $

The left sum splits the numbers 16 and 10 into 1,6 and 1 (1+6+1+0) so what we get it 1+6+1+1+2+1+1 = 13 with 7 remaining up to nearest multiple of 10, making the last digit 7.

To begin with, one could calculate the probability of collision for random numbers where the first 6 digits are random dates in reasonble time (1950-2010) and digit 7 and 8 are random, and then try to understand what probability was discussed.

A mathematical ansatz could be that there is 1/10 probability for the first of the last four digits, 1/10 for the second and 1/5 for the third (=0.002) but then the last digit would collide dependent on all the others.

Comment: I don't think this is clear. In particular, it is not clear where those other $18$ numbers came from. How long are the id's?  What "checksum" must be satisfied?

Comment: It certainly matters whether the two numbers are random or sequential.  There are about $9,000$ births a year in Sweden,  so around $12$ of each sex on any given day.  If the numbers are sequential, starting at $00$ each day, they have a small range.

Comment: I think it would be very helpfull if you could add an example of one full id and point out what each digit stands for (in case you know). 
The checksum is always defined as 10 - last digit of sum of numbers? (for example for sum 25 it would be 5, or 10-5; for 112 it would be 8 or 10-2)

Comment: @TinglTanglBob Yes, I think so

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, *but* we could create bounds for the probability anyway, right?

Comment: @lulu  I updated the question with elaboration. Is it easier to understand ?

Comment: Not for me.  I don't understand where the new $16$ numbers are coming from.  At first I thought the $2\,1\,2\,1\,2\,1\,2\,1\,2$ was just telling you the parity of each digit in the first row, but that isn't it (as the final $5$ would then yield a $1$ not a $2$).  And I have no guess where $16\,1\,1\,2\,1\,1\,0\,1\,10$ comes from, nor if I am even reading it correctly.

Comment: Note:  the third row is $\textit{not}$ the product of the first two, at least not in any sense I can figure.  Sure $8\times 2=16$ and $1\times 1=1$ but $0\times 2\neq 1$ and $1\times 1\neq 0$

Comment: @lulu That was a mistake because my example is contrived, but the scheme is the same. I tried to fix it just now.

Comment: I'm not sure it's worth the trouble to clarify it, but I still don't understand the second row either.  As I say, it is almost the parity of the first, but not quite.  However, since we don't know how two of the final four numbers are chosen, I really don't think anybody can say much about the probability.

Comment: @lulu Worth what, are you going to sell something or why bother about what's worth? I don't believe that multiplication is difficult to understand, we could assume that the two digits are random for one calculation and you cannot believe that my question is the only source of information about have this is done, can you ?